# ИНС неправильно выстраивает синусоиду

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Недавно начал изучать ИНС и решил сделать простую ИНС, которая умела бы предсказывать значение синуса при определённой радиане.
Подготовил данные:

```
args_len = 200
input = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi, args_len).reshape(-1,1)
output = np.sin(input).reshape(-1,1)#np.random.uniform(-1,1,args_len).reshape(-1,1)
data =  np.hstack((input, output) )

input_train_data, input_test_data, output_train_data, output_test_data = train_test_split(data[:,0], data[:,1], test_size=0.3)
input_train_data = input_train_data.reshape(-1,1)
input_test_data = input_test_data.reshape(-1,1)
output_test_data = output_test_data.reshape(-1,1)
output_train_data = output_train_data.reshape(-1,1)

fig = px.scatter(x=data[:,0], y=data[:,1], title="y=sin(rad)")
fig.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Построил ИНС на keras и обучил:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add( Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid", input_shape=(1,)) )
model.add( Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid") )
model.add( Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid") )

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="Adamax")
model.fit(input_train_data, output_train_data, epochs=1500, batch_size=20)
result = model.evaluate(input_test_data, output_test_data,verbose=2)
result = model.evaluate(input_test_data, output_test_data, verbose=1)
print(result)
>>0.34740047256151835
```

Потом я пытаюсь предсказать тестовые данные:

```
predict_input = input_test_data
predict_output = model.predict(predict_input)
fig = px.scatter(x = predict_input.reshape(1,-1)[0], y = predict_output.reshape(1,-1)[0], title="y=sin(rad)")
fig.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно выстраивается совсем не синусоида, скорее сигмоида. Почему так? Может я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: А что ещё вы можете получить после activation="sigmoid"? :)

Comment: @CrazyElf А какая у него должна быть функция активации у последнего нейрона? Разве суть сигмоиды заключается не в том, что она максимально нелинейно и следовательно может принимать нелинейный вид?

Comment: Вот именно, что сигмоида старается растащить выход максимально близко к значениям 0 и 1, что вы и наблюдаете.

Comment: Основная ошибка у вас в неправильной архитектуре сети - для скрытых слоев нужно использовать нелинейные функции активации, но не сигмоиду - она сжимает значения и для более глубоких НС появляется эффект исчезающего градиента. А для выходного слоя сигмоиду использют только для задач бинарной классификации - у вас же задача регрессии, поэтому на выходном слое нужна линейная функция активации

Comment: @MaxU это единственная ошибка или есть ещё?

Comment: @CrazyElf это единственная ошибка или есть ещё?

Comment: @parvektor Ну я прямо ответ написал с рабочим примером

Comment: @MaxU я правильно понимаю, что выход сигмоиды в задачах бинарной классификации интерпретируют в качестве вероятности т.к. область определения у этой функции [0;1]?

Comment: @parvektor, да, все верно. Только не область определения, а область значений)

Comment: @parvektor Или как "степень уверенности в ответе", что в общем одно и то же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, нужно побольше размерность слоёв и линейную активацию на выходе:

```
n = 50
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=n, activation="relu", input_shape=(1,)) )
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=n, activation="relu", input_shape=(n,)) )
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="linear", input_shape=(n,)) )

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(input_train_data, output_train_data, epochs=500, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
result = model.evaluate(input_test_data, output_test_data,verbose=2)
print(result)

[0.00045047128029788536, 0.014124496839940548]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я понял почему нужно использовать линейную функцию акивации на выходном слое, но не понимаю почему на входном слое и выходных слоях мы используем relu(разве relu не определена на [0,+inf] и тем самым не будет гасить отрицательные значения? Или эта проблема решается с помощью нейрона смещения?) и причём так много. Я понимаю, что вопросы могут показаться вам глупым, но я недавно начал изучать эту тему

Comment: @parvektor Да я сам то не такой уж спец по нейросетям. В общем, relu тут лучше и да, я думаю это решается смещением, наверное на последнем линейном слое опять же.